# DNS format error in syslog, how to debug?

Tags: domain-name-system, syslog

I'm getting an error in my `syslog` when resolving a domain I also the DNS for.

```
Nov 24 21:51:55 moo named[4075]: DNS format error from 192.227.143.105#53 resolving bostonyoungentrepreneurs.com/NS for client 127.0.0.1#65133: invalid response
Nov 24 21:51:55 moo named[4075]: DNS format error from 192.227.143.105#53 resolving bostonyoungentrepreneurs.com/AAAA for client 127.0.0.1#39972: invalid response
```

Is there any way I can properly debug this and see why it's an invalid response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most likely by executing:

```
dig ns problematic-domain.com @127.0.0.1
dig aaaa problematic-domain.com @127.0.0.1
```

or

```
host -t ns problematic-domain.com 127.0.0.1
host -t aaaa problematic-domain.com 127.0.0.1
```

From what I see problem with that domain comes from the fact that two nameservers responsible for that domain have the same ip as the record in question:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-P2 <<>> ns problematic-domain.com. +noall +answ
;; global options: +cmd
problematic-domain.com. 172265 IN NS ns1.problematic-domain.com.
problematic-domain.com. 172265 IN NS ns2.problematic-domain.com.
ns1.problematic-domain.com. 172265 IN A   192.227.143.105
ns2.problematic-domain.com. 172265 IN A   192.227.143.105
```

Comment: Should I just have it as one nameserver then?

Comment: @Axsuul At *least* two, with different IPs, as geographically far from each other as possible. As it stands, whenever your single IP becomes briefly unreachable your domain vanishes from the internet.